# Does it make sense to mix JdbcTemplate with CrudRepository?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am quite familiar with the `JdbcTemplate` object of Spring (and with spring-jdbc in general), and I really like writing the SQL and dealing with the object mapping myself.

However recently I was playing with the `CrudRepository` interface and I really liked it.

That said, I still favor writing my own SQLs queries when it comes to a complex query (joins and so on).

I would like to be able to use the `CrudRepository` methods in a class that also has a `JdbcTemplate` instance, that way I could have the out of the box methods of `CrudRepository` while being able to write my own complex SQLs and use them with `JdbcTemplate`.

The problem is, of course, that `CrudRepository` is just an interface while `JdbcTemplate` is a regular class. So the question is

1. Does any of what I am mentioning actually make sense?
2. Assuming that answer to (1) is yes, how would I be able to have a class with an instance of a `JdbcTemplate` that also provides an implementation of `CrudRepository` without having to hack my way around it too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixing JPA and JDBC is very well possible in any application. The [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) can be used to write complex queries or do complexer custom mapping. Another option is to use a `RowCallbackHandler` (instead of a `RowMapper` to directly stream something to a file or other resource, to preserve memory).

When using Spring Data you can use the [`@Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/Query.html) annotation to write custom queries in a repository. This can be a native query or JPQL.

However there is nothing in Spring preventing you from using both in a single class. You could directly inject your repository into a service as well as the `JdbcTemplate` (or you could put that behind another facade if you like).

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class YourService {

    private final YourCrudRepository repo;
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    public YourService(YourCrudRepository repo, JdbcTemplate jdbc) {
        this.repo=repo;
        this.jdbc=jdbc;
    }

    // Your methods go down here
}
```

Now you can use both. The nice thing about Spring is that regardless of using the `CrudRepository` or the `JdbcTemplate` it will throw the same exceptions, the `DataAccessException`. If they operate on the same `DataSource` a single `JpaTransactionManager` is enough to manage the connection and transaction.

Comment: Is the jdbcTemplate aware of the entity manager 1st level cache and flushing strategy? I would doubt that. So this opens the room for inconsistent and unexpected behavior. Do you have more experience regarding this?

Comment: Ofcourse it isn't, so it is wise to do a `flush` before using the jdbc template (or you could use some AOP to automate this). Unless you are sure that everything already has been flused.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use them as members?

```
public class MyDao {
    private JdbcTemplate template;
    private CrudRepository repository;
}
```

Of course you would need to pass through all methods, which is kind on noisy. `Dao` would be the stereotype **D**ata **A**ccess **O**bject.

Comment: I thought of that, but then I will need to expose all the methods of `CrudRepository` in the `MyDao` class and it would get convoluted :(